# How to sort Product by it's parent category position

Tags: magento-1, sort

```
$sale_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$sale_products->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                               'image',
                               'name',
                               'short_description', 
               ))
               ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
               ))
               ->addFieldToFilter('feature', array('eq' => 1))
               ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')
               ->addFinalPrice()
               ->getSelect()
               ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
```

Right now I only know how to sort by position. and I believe the position is sorted by the date item become sale.

If I sort by `->addAttributeToSort('category_id', 'ASC')` I am not sure if it have any effect.  b/c product have many category ids.  and I can't find a pattern that match.

How to sort Product by it's parent category position?

Comment: Did you try something like this: Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSort('position','asc'); ?

Comment: No, but I think what you did was filter out the category.  so it's is only displaying items in that category.  what I want is item in all category but sorted in the position the category position as listed in admin

Comment: There's one big problem with what you want to achieve. It's the fact that the same product can belong to several categories with a different position. The position itself is stored under the catalog_category_product table if you want to check the structure is very simple but in your case, it makes the solution a little bit complex.

Comment: @DigitalPianism I just want to filter it at a level2 ( one directly under root, which each product only have one cat assigned to ).  is there a way to do that? with out loop through 2 `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your products are only assigned to one category, I reckon you could do something like this, you may have to make modifications to get it working with your current code, but that gives you a good idea on how to do it:

```
$sale_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
$sale_products->getSelect()->joinLeft(
'ccp'=>'catalog_category_product',
'main_table.category_id = ccp.category_id and main_table.entity_id = ccp.product_id',
array('ccp.position'));
$sale_products->getSelect()->order('ccp.position asc');
```